# react.js error ** can not update during an existing state transition **

Tags: reactjs

can anyone please tell me why I getting this error when redirecting the user when the user has not shippingAddress data?
I'm sure the problem is with the **props.history.push** . when I comment it out , no error happens.

```
const PaymentMethodScreen = (props) => {

    const [paymentMethod, setPaymentMethod] = useState("PayPal");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

     const cart = useSelector(state => state.cartReducer);
     const { shippingAddress } = cart;
     if(!!shippingAddress){
         props.history.push('/shipping')
    };
     const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({
          type: actions.CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
          payload: paymentMethod,
        });
        props.history.push("/placeholder");
      };

       return (
        <div>
        <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 />
        <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
         // *not useful*
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="primary" type="submit">
              Continue
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
       )

};

export default PaymentMethodScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are accidentally navigating to another page while the dispatch hasn't finished updating the store yet**

To solve this, wait for your dispatch to finish before navigate:

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await dispatch({
    type: actions.CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
    payload: paymentMethod,
  });
  props.history.push("/placeholder");
};
```